# Homeomorphic closed subspaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space, and $U,V\subseteq X$ two subspaces of $X$ such that $U\cong V$ ($U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic) with respect the subspace topology of $X$. I know examples where $U$ is closed in $X$ and $V$ is not. Is there some conditions to guarantee the next statement:

If $U$ is closed in $X$, then $V$ es closed in $X$.

Comment: When $X$ is compact Hausdorff

Comment: Curious to know a counterexample in the general case.

Comment: @user4894 $\Bbb R \cong (0,1)$

Comment: Following the path of @HennoBrandsma, also if $X$ is countably compact and first countable. The problem is that I have an example where exactly $X$ is not compact and not first countable. So maybe there is no hope :(.

Comment: @MikeMiller Silly of me to ask before thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, then a subspace is closed if and only if it is compact. Since compactness is a topological invariant, $X$ being compact Hausdorff ensures that if two subspaces are homeomorphic and one is closed, then so is the other.